# I need to change the TextColor of the sub item in my Preference Page

Tags: android, xml

This is only changing the title of the preference.
I need to change the Sub item where the user will input a number
Looked Everywhere cannot find a solution.
Please Help.

XML :

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:title="@string/app_name"


>
<EditTextPreference
    android:title="@string/wage_title_preference"
    android:key="@string/wage_key"
    android:defaultValue="@string/wage_default_preference"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

    android:singleLine="true">

</EditTextPreference>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean the placeholder? If yes try this

```
<EditTextPreference
android:title="@string/wage_title_preference"
android:key="@string/wage_key"
android:defaultValue="@string/wage_default_preference"
android:inputType="text"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:textColorHint="Your color"
android:singleLine="true">

</EditTextPreference>
```

Comment: No it doesint do it. I need to change the text color of the number under the Wage title.